# JQuery event is still being loaded even if the DOM has been removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this markup

```
  <html>
     <body>
       <div id ="wrap">
         <div id = "main-content">
           <!-- more markup here -->
           <script>
          $(window).scroll(function(){
           if($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() $(window).height())*0.7) {
               alert("SCROLLED") 
             }}); 
           </script>
         </div>
       </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

and I am usually doing ajax calls to remove the contents of "main-content" and I do that using this

```
   $.get(sampleUrl, function(data) {
        var newTitle = $(data).filter('title').text();
        $('#main-content').children().remove();
        $('#main-content').html($(data).find('#main-content').html());
    },"html");
```

However the above code removes only the DOM not the javascript events like "scroll" event, is there anyway I can remove/unbind it?

Comment: Isn't there an `.unbind()` method? Or `.off()` or something?

Answer (score 4):

When a `script` tag is put on the page it executes. It will make an `eventListener` for scrolling on the `window`. Removing any content inside `main-content` will not undo a listener, and your `window` will obviously still exist.

You want to call `$(window).off('scroll')` when you want that behavior to stop.

`$(window).unbind` is an older way of doing things that is deprecated.

**Sidenote:**

You want to avoid putting inline JS if you can.

Comment: [Technically `.unbind()` isn't deprecated according to the docs, but `.off()` is the current "preferred" way](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/), so this is the best answer.

Comment: @user568458 Yeah easier to say deprecated than preferred, although you are right we know one day they will get rid of it. It's just a pass-through function under the hood AFAIK.

Comment: However not all of the pages I am loading has a scroll effect. will it have a performance impact?

Comment: You want to have that binding when you want to listen for a scroll. Anytime you are listening to a scroll it WILL have a performance impact as the user scrolls.

Comment: Essentially you should bind on the pages you want to listen, then unbind when you switch pages, using `.on` and `.off`. You may also want to throttle your callback so it doesn't run on every single `scroll` event... maybe once every `250ms` or some other number that makes it feel smooth.

Answer (score 1):

`$(window).off('scroll')` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

The event is bound to the *window* - where on the page the `script` tag was makes no difference after the code is executed and the event is bound.

---

Actually `unbind()` is the old-school way, these days `$(window).off('scroll');` is ["preferred"](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) - unless you're stuck using a legacy version of jQuery older than 1.7. `unbind()` still works, ain't deprecated yet, but there's always the chance it might be.

Comment: I hope if he picks yours he at least upvotes mine too and visa versa ;)

Comment: Ha! Easy javascript questions almost always get near-simultaneous answers